# Unable to assign new shortcut keys in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

The assign key is disabled for creating to new shortcuts for commands. Is there anyway to 'fix' this or a reason why it's disabled? My Visual Studio 2019 is up to date and I program in C++ if that information helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on `Press Shortcut Keys` assign a key by pressing or multiple pressing keyboard keys then Assign appears .

Comment: Oh I see, is there anyway to assign a shortcut as a single key?

Comment: @FLy1nRabBit yea there is i think but it will warns you there is already assigned then you have to remove key where it assigned then use that key

Comment: @FLy1nRabBit you have to check your shortcut keys if they are currently in use or not.